# constituent detail report not working (timeout)

Tags: civireport

I am using CiviCRM 4.5.8, an instance with 18,328 contacts.

No matter how long I set the max execution time of a page, I am getting a timeout when trying to view the constituent detail report (instance 2). The other reports all work fine.

Has anyone ever experienced this? Can anyone think of a reason this might be happening? The PHP error logs are showing nothing but a timeout, and the CiviCRM log is showing nothing.

**Update:** It seems to be related to Activities. If I create a new report based on constituent detail, and uncheck all the activity columns from being used, then the report is produced ok. If I check one column to do with activities again, then it stops working and times out.

Answer (score 1):

1. How many activities do you have (i.e. the number of rows in the activity table)
2. Where are you hosting the site
3. Is your database on the same server as the web server

If i had to guess, i suspect your activity table is quite large and the left join with the contact tables is basically causing the query to take forever and hence the timeout

Comment: Hi donald, thanks for replying. I have 24,000 activities. If I search for activities with type "bulk email" then the search times out, but it doesn't for any other activity search. But there are only 24 bulk email type activities in the database. The database is on the same server as the web server. I am hosting the site on Layershift.